# Python - Whats the best way to run a method/function based on Time. (24h)

Tags: python, time

I have been thinking to run a script/code on a time that I want. Like we say etc. I want to run a program at 00:00 (I enter it in the code that I want to start at that time) meanwhile it's 23:21. So it should wait until that time and then run the method/function or whatever it should do.

What would be in that case the best way to run something like this in that case :) ?

EDIT: Exemple -

> I was thinking like to do it through a code. Like etc. I have a code
>   with we say 3 functions. At the time 23:50 I want function nr 1 to
>   run. Then at 23:55 i want the function nr 2 to run and then 00:05 i
>   want the function nr3 to run and all that in the same py file.

Comment: If it's an isolated program you could use Task Scheduler (for Windows) or cron (for Linux)

Comment: Oh. Well it is not a program itself I would say. My bad for saying it. I would just assume it is a code and I want the method/function to start at a time given.

Comment: There is no way for a program to start **itself**. Either you use a system service (like aforementioned cron) to start your program, **or** you start your program by hand, but code it so it sleeps until the right time, then does something and goes to sleep again.

Comment: I edited my post. Maybe that will give a another ideas through that :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **crontab**.

To edit:

```
crontab -e
```

To add initial time:

```
50 23 * * * /usr/bin/python /your/file.py function1
55 23 * * * /usr/bin/python /your/file.py function2
05 00 * * * /usr/bin/python /your/file.py function3
```

And it should be like this your file.

```
import sys

def function1():
    print "function 1 running"
def function2():
    print "function 2 running"
def function3():
    print "function 3 running"

if sys.argv[1]:
    run = sys.argv[1]
    if run == "function1":
      function1()
    elif run == "function2":
       function2()
    elif run == "function3":
       function3()
```

Comment: I think I was missunderstood with my question. Well basically what I want is that I have etc  we say 3 functions. At the time 23:50 I want function nr 1 to run. Then at 23:55 i want the function nr 2 to run and then 00:05 i want the function nr3 to run and all that in the same py file

Comment: If you use arguments, you can do it. Like this: `python file.py function1`

Comment: Oh dang, Will that work? I thought more like inside my code, Im not really good at python (Beginner only) and I thought there is a function like to be easier way already inbuilt. Then I just add it inside the code. But I assume there isnt anything like that?

Comment: @WhenInThis There is, but in its simplest form, it does consumes a bit of ressource, not much, but it is far to be optimal. In a bit more complicated way, you use a thread for each of your function.

Comment: Looks awesome! I think its something that im looking for!

Answer (score 1):

[sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler.enterabs) library is what you are looking for. No site-packages or another utilities like cron are required.

Comment: I think I was missunderstood with my question. Well basically what I want is that I have etc  we say 3 functions. At the time 23:50 I want function nr 1 to run. Then at 23:55 i want the function nr 2 to run and then 00:05 i want the function nr3 to run and all that in the same py file

Comment: And what does make you thinking that i missunderstood you? If you want to run code from itself without sleeping in process list - you can't do it without cron or task scheduller. If sleeping process is acceptable for you - why don't use sched?

Comment: Oh well. You might be right. I havent checked the library clearly but I will look into it now. It might be the one im looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import time
starttimes = { (23, 50): func1, (23, 55): func2, (0, 5): func3 }

while True:
    now = tuple(time.gmtime()[3:5])
    if now in starttimes:
        starttimes[now]() # call a function 
    time.sleep(60)
```

Mind that it is a very crude solution, assuming in particular that none of `func1`…`func3` functions will run for longer time than the period left to the starting time of the next function. Also: you need to start your program and leave it running all the time. You kill it (or reboot your system), you need to start it again.

Comment: You should put this snippet in a thread, would be less resource consuming, regardless the OP needs to do something else with his program in the meanwhile or not.

Comment: Oh okey. Yeah you are right. I will most def. Look into it. but I thought also Thread might be a sort of solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a dedicated task scheduler like [Celer](http://www.celeryproject.org/)y.

Or to do it simply, you can put a crontab to run a python script to run every minute.
Store method name and time to run in a database. When the task runs, it sees if there is any task to be run for the minute,and executes the method specified in the database.

Comment: Oh okey but I was thinking like to do it through a code. Like etc. I have a code with we say 3 functions. At the time 23:50 I want function nr 1 to run. Then at 23:55 i want the function nr 2 to run and then 00:05 i want the function nr3 to run and all that in the same py file.